# How to CountIF specific same text and total it in another tab in the same googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets, counting, countif

I want to calculate the same text/value in the entire columnA of Tab1 and calculate the Total in a single cell in Tab2, but on the same sheet in googlesheet:

I [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HES1A.jpg)currently built this code;

```
=COUNTIF("Ads Sharing!B2:B", "<>Christian")
```

Let me know if this is possible in googlesheets, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIF('Ads Sharing'!B2:B, "<>Christian")
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I'm too close but the special characters I placed made the code wrong. thanks again for help.